# The image won't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image at the end wont appear. I am a noob coder and just starting out. I don't know how to make the image appear. can I pls have some help? Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>HTML in sublime text 3</title>

 <style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
</style>

</head>
<body style='background-color:black;'>

 <span style='font-family: fantasy'><h1><center>How to code with HTML in sublime text 3</center></h1></span>
 <span style='font-family: arial'><h2><center>By liam Ferguson</center></h2></span>
</body>
<p>_________________________________________________________________________________
 
</p>
<p>
 <span style='font-family: cursive'><P>Sublime Text 3 is a coding program that allows you to edit programs, crete programs and edit text</P></span>
</p>
<img src="screenshot(30).png" alt="A shot of code" width="100" height="100"/>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the image path? also your HTML path?

Comment: Remove the (30) from the image. If that takes you to another image then redownload the image as something else. The width and height aren't defined by PX (pixels, which is PX)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an image called `screenshot(30).png` in the same place as wherever your HTML file is.  Images are found relative to the HTML file that refers to them.

Answer (score -1):

The alt text is being displayed because the image couldn't be loaded. Is the image file in the same directory as your html file?